# How can I allow my program permanent authorization for one spotify account (my own) with the spotify api?

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I am building a local desktop app where I can read, classify, and create playlists.
The following auth code I have is:

```
##oauth

scope = "playlist-modify-public playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private"

sp = spotipy.Spotify(


          auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(
          client_id=client_id,
          client_secret=client_secret,
          redirect_uri= "https://example.com/callback/",    
          scope= scope, open_browser=False))
```

when run on cmd, this asks to click the link generated and then to paste the link that I was redirected to. I want to know if there is another way to provide authorization (automatically or permanently) so that my .exe app doesn't run into an error.

code in your response would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot grant permanent access to the APIs in a single call, but you can refresh your token automatically whenever the access expires, as shown [in the docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/).

If you're using Python, I recommend to do this via [Spotipy](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy), which makes the auth process much easier (see https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/master/#authorization-code-flow)